# Recursive Types in dataclass-wizard YAML

Tags: python, yaml, python-dataclasses

I'm attempting to build a simple data-class example for YAML parsing which consists of recursive types.

The YAML in question looks like this:

```yaml
---
folders:
  - name: a
    children:
      - name: b
  - name: c
    children: []
```

The way I am defining my types is like so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import annotations  # I'm on Python 3.9
from dataclass_wizard import YAMLWizard, LoadMeta
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class DemoManifest(YAMLWizard):
    folders: List[DemoFolder]


@dataclass
class DemoFolder(YAMLWizard):
    name: str
    children: List[DemoFolder]


def main():
    LoadMeta(recursive=True).bind_to(DemoFolder)
    manifest = DemoManifest.from_yaml_file("recurse.yml")
    print(manifest)
```

It's a pretty simple example. I have one outer type which defines a list of `DemoFolder` objects, which potentially have a list of children of `DemoFolder` types as well.

When I run this, I get a `RecursionError`, `maximum depth exceeded`. Clearly somehow recursion is breaking the parsing. I thought that I solved the issue using the meta above, but it is definitely not working.

Is it possible to do self-referential deserialization in YAML for `dataclass-wizard`?

---

**EDIT:** This is not an issue of Python compiling. The code compiles and runs, it seems to be an issue with `dataclass-wizard`, which is where the recursion occurs.

Comment: This is not an issue of Python compiling, the future `annotations` trick works and it's fine. It's specifically in the dataclass-wizard library that the problem emerges here when trying to deserialize a self-referential class.

Comment: Hi there! I just saw this post and I thought it illustrated a common problem. I'm actually working through other issues in the linked project now (most noticeably with the `Generic` types) but def I'd be interested in supporting recursive references to dataclasses at some point. I feel like I have a general idea of how to accomplish it, but i'd just need to sit down and put it down on paper. Btw I am well aware of this error in particular, I just have not gotten around to opening an issue on it yet.

Comment: @rv.kvetch thank you so much for your response, I'll try to find another way around my particular problem.

Comment: No problem! also don't hesitate to open an issue on the project repo in the meantime, however I definitely think recursive types is an important goal for the library to support. Btw one other thing I can point out is that the `recursive=True` only means the Meta config is applied recursively to nested classes, so again probably it is not what you are looking for in this case.